# In Azure do i get charged for both a virtual machine and cloud services?

Tags: azure

I have been playing around with azure to replace my small web server and I was wondering the following. In azure it says that I have 1 virtual machine and 1 cloud service. On the pricing calculator it says that for $15.02 i get a virtual machine and the same if i get cloud services. Does this mean I'm paying 30.04 a month and if so can i get rid of cloud services?

Thankyou for any guidance :).

Pricing Calc. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=cloud

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only get charged for the VMs you have running.  The cloud service you see in the management portal is only a container for the IaaS VM.  The pricing calculator is referring to PaaS WebRoles and WorkerRoles when it says 'Cloud Services'.

So in your case it would only be $15.02.